Standard loop control: controller parameters calculation
Hello engineering community! Could anyone help me with the following homework question:

Here is the translation:
"Given the system G(s) and the controller R(s) of a standard control loop with the disturbance z(t).
a) Calculate the range of values for K_P and K_D so that the closed control loop is stable and has the amplitude reserve Ar = 4."
This was my attempt, which I stopped after I was told it was wrong:

